# Visual Basic, Child Thread Blocking Main Thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, copy, blocking

I've run into a little issue with a simple file copying application I'm writing in Visual Basic 2005. I have a main thread which looks after the GUI, and for the file scanning/copying I've created a separate thread which I create like this:

```
    trd_copy = New Thread(AddressOf CopyTask)
    trd_copy.IsBackground = True
    trd_copy.Start()
```

This works fine for the scanning phase of the operation, and I can use the buttons in the GUI just fine. The problem is that when CopyTask gets to the file copying phase (using File.Copy), the main thread appears to lock up, and the GUI with it, meaning that the button I have there for aborting the copy operation is useless. When the copying is done, all returns to normal, and during copying the sub thread can update the status bar on the main form.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't for the life of me see what it is.

Thanks very much!

Edit: Adding the code for CopyTask():

```
Private Sub CopyTask()
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    If check_scanfirst.Checked Then
        status1.Text = "Scanning..."
        bytestocopy = 0
        scandir(src)

        filesscanned = True
        MsgBox("Scanning completed")
    End If

    If check_delete.Checked Then
        ' Do a clean of the destination, removing any files that don't exist in the source dir
    End If

    If filesscanned Then
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
        ProgressBar1.Refresh()
    End If

    checkdir(src)
    MsgBox("Copying completed")
    If filesfailed > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Warning: " + Str(filesfailed) + " files were not copied successfully.")
    End If
    guistop()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm.. code for CopyTask?

Comment: Are you by chance using `Invoke()` in `CopyTask()`?  A common mistake is to invoke the entire method thus negating the creating of the thread in the first place...

Comment: Sorry, should've added it - it's in the main question now. Not using Invoke at all. I'm relatively new to this, coming from a firmware coding / Blitz Basic background so I'm only learning...

Like I said, the scandir() part works as expected, recursing through dirs, and the main form is responsive and is updated. checkdir() is exactly the same code only adds a File.Copy call to each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can tell all calls to the System are also GUI Thread based no matter if you want them or not. And Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False is very bad, you always want to write your thread and ( if beginner ) run code and everytime it breaks out to code to write a delegate and an invoke function for that part of your thread ( taking up the most minimal time ) one can in the Gui(Main) thread.

Here is an example with full sourcecode

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15104/Multithreading-with-VB-NET-A-beginner-s-choice

> in your thread

Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False -- this needs removed
    If check_scanfirst.Checked Then             -- this needs a delegate and invoke method
        status1.Text = "Scanning..."             -- this needs a delegate and invoke method
        bytestocopy = 0
        scandir(src)             -- if scandir(has calls to gui )this needs a delegate and invoke method but inside of Scandir()

```
    filesscanned = True
    MsgBox("Scanning completed")              -- this needs a delegate and invoke method ( keep in mind thread will keep running even if mesgbox not clicked )
End If

If check_delete.Checked Then              -- this needs a delegate and invoke method
    ' Do a clean of the destination, removing any files that don't exist in the source dir
End If

If filesscanned Then
    ProgressBar1.Visible = True             -- this needs a delegate and invoke method
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0             -- this needs a delegate and invoke method
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100             -- this needs a delegate and invoke method
    ProgressBar1.Refresh()             -- this needs a delegate and invoke method
End If

checkdir(src)
MsgBox("Copying completed")             -- this needs a delegate and invoke method
If filesfailed > 0 Then
    MsgBox("Warning: " + Str(filesfailed) + " files were not copied successfully.")             -- this needs a delegate and invoke method
End If
guistop()             -- this needs a delegate and invoke method if (guistop makes calls to gui )
```

so if you can't tell your making lots of calls to the gui... heres how i would write it to make it really simple

> how i would write your code ( wrote this in word some code may need a tweak )

```
Private sub DoStuffBeforeCopy()
If check_scanfirst.Checked Then
    status1.Text = "Scanning..."
    bytestocopy = 0
trd_copy.ParameterizedStart(src) //start thread
end sub

CopyTask(byval src as *string*?)
    scandir(src) – put the code here or make another thread ( src is better )
    filesscanned = True

    invoke-MsgBox("Scanning completed")

    invoke If check_delete.Checked Then

    If filesscanned Then
        Invoke-ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        Invoke-ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
        Invoke-ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
        Invoke-ProgressBar1.Refresh()
    End If

    checkdir(src) – put the code here or make another thread ( src is better )

    invoke-MsgBox("Copying completed")

    If filesfailed > 0 Then
        Invoke-MsgBox("Warning: " + Str(filesfailed) + " files were not copied successfully.")
    End If

    guistop()– put the code here or make another thread ( src is better )

End sub
```

**** DO THIS FOR ANY Delegat / invoke needed

> for threads calls with parameters

trd_copy.ParameterizedStart(src)

```
Delegate Sub nameofDelegate(s As Integer)
Sub nameofDelegate+NameofSub(ByVal s As Integer)
    If Form1.ProgressBar1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New nameofDelegate (AddressOf nameofDelegate+NameofSub)
        NameOfYourForm.Invoke(d, New Object() {s})
    Else
        If s = 1 Then
            NameOfYourForm.ProgressBar1.Refresh() ** Or other Gui Functions
        Else

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

> For Thread calls without parametrs

trd_copy.Start()

```
Delegate Sub nameofDelegate()
Sub nameofDelegate+NameofSub()
    If Form1.ProgressBar1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New nameofDelegate (AddressOf nameofDelegate+NameofSub)
        NameOfYourForm.Invoke(d, New Object())
    Else
       NameOfYourForm.ProgressBar1.Refresh() ** Or other Gui Functions
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much Pakk, I'll try it out tomorrow evening and let you know how I get on. It makes a bit of sense, but I still don't understand why I need to delegate things like the MsgBox - I want them to be blocking, they're really only there for debugging. The scandir() works exactly as expected and is recursive so I can't put the code there, and I don't see why it should need another thread. Likewise for checkdir. I was expecting that since the CopyTask code was a separate thread, the scandir() and checkdir() routines would also run in the CopyTask thread.

Comment: Your welcome, you want the delegates because you want to keep the interaction with the main thread at minimum, so a invoke would cost you 1 ms interaction ( hanging it up for that long ) and the entire thread up to how ever long it lasts. The msgbox's you don't really need once released ( if there only there for debug i'd leave them in  ) I still would recomend the Scandir() to be inside of the thread ( only if it doesnt make UI calls - otherwise there can be very many delegate / invoke calls ) but any way hope this works for you

Comment: So what do you mean by inside the thread? If it's called from the thread, is it not part of that thread? I can't put the code directly in the CopyTask as it's recursive - it calls itself for every directory it comes across in the path 'src' so it's just a private sub. Scandir() has no system calls and works fine, but checkdir() has a File.Copy which, if I comment it out, works around the issue. So it looks like it is as you say, the system calls which are bogging it down. I'll report back later on. Thanks again :)

Comment: Anything at all to do with GUI or Main Thread needs invoked and is part of the new Thread but because you are accessing the Main Thread and Changing Parts of it : hense the checkforilligalcrossthreads=false) you need to invoke those methods. 
Im sure someone more knowledgable then I can explain better.
File Copy should be fine, you need to be more conserned about msgbox's and textbox1.text changes and other Form(MainThread) changes rather then the system calls :) --- i try to think of it

Comment: this way, if it doesnt change my form, i don't need to invoke it... if i change even the smallest label or want to set something to .visible=false , i have to invoke it

Comment: If you have the Time this is a really good way to learn more about *Multi-Threading Cross Threading Safe Calls :* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read of that. And thanks for your time - as I said, this is all very foreign to me when I used to just use fork() and some semaphores to make sure everything played nice.

Comment: you are welcome, if you wish to decide to start working on Threads in different model you need to do i a bit different you can just email me if you wish.