# Locking a Control from Another Thread in Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, design-patterns

I am developing a parser application to build a call tree from DDL files that have been extracted from a database.  The idea is to take a large number of these DDL files and determine exactly what calls what.  To do this I am using a .NET TreeView.  The final output I am working toward is something like this:

```
-Proc1
  -Proc2
    -Proc3
  -Proc4
-Proc2
  -Proc3
-Proc3
-Proc4
```

Now, all of my parsing is working correctly.  Though, this process is quite lengthy.  As such I have decided to move all of the heavyweight processing onto its own thread.  Everything is working as intended until I get to the point where I need to update my TreeView.  I am attempting to keep all of the actual update logic on the separate thread and only update the TreeView.  However, despite having my main form SyncLocked, I am still getting an exception when I try to access the tree.

I have found quite a few examples online that show how to use Delegates for thread-safe access but, unfortunately, they are all a bit simplistic for my needs.  Most simply show how to set a text property.  As I mentioned before, I am trying to keep as much of the processing as possible on the worker thread and only call the respective TreeView methods to update as this process can be quite long winded (hundreds of procedures to parse and display at a time).

Is there a good way to do this or should I just take my lumps and pass my entire dependency tree back to my main form?

Here is the code I am currently using to display the first level of dependencies. Remember, this will eventually be recursive (currently in "get it working" mode) which is why I want to keep it off the UI thread:

```
Public Sub updateTreeView()

    Dim arrNodeList As ArrayList
    Dim childNode As clsProcedureNode
    Dim currentNode As clsProcedureNode
    Dim intChildIndex As Integer
    Dim intNodeListIndex As Integer
    Dim treeView As TreeView

    //Lock main form
    SyncLock mMainForm

        //Check that we are actually running on a seprate thread
        If mMainForm.InvokeRequired() = True Then

            //Call delegate to get handle to TreeView
            treeView = mMainForm.Invoke(mGetTreeViewDelegate)

            //Add Parsed array to main form TreeView
            For intNodeListIndex = 0 To mProcedureNodes.Length - 1

                //Get current node and its child list
                currentNode = mProcedureNodes(intNodeListIndex)
                arrNodeList = currentNode.getProcsCalled()

                //Add node and all children to TreeView
                With treeView
                    .BeginUpdate()
                    .Nodes.Add(currentNode.getName())
                    For intChildIndex = 0 To arrNodeList.Count
                        childNode = arrNodeList.Item(intChildIndex)
                        .Nodes(intNodeListIndex).Nodes.Add(childNode.getName())
                    Next
                    .EndUpdate()
                End With
            Next
        End If   
    End SyncLock   
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you have to manipulate the treeview on the UI thread? You pull the treeview out of the mainform and then populate it on the thread. I think you need to pass the data back to the UI thread and then populate it there.

Comment: That is actually what I am trying to avoid.  The process occurs in two steps.  The DDL files are parsed and then the tree is built.  Due to the very large and recursive nature of the data set I am working with, I am trying to do the tree building off-thread so the UI doesn't hang while the tree is populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)? It's way easier to use than Invoke and synchronization. In fact, it was designed to ease things like this.

You can do your background work in `DoWork` event handler which runs on other thread and safely interact with you UI in `ProgressChanged` event handler which runs on UI thread. The need for invoking `ProgressChanged` is signaled in `DoWork` using `ReportProgress` method of `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: I had seen BackgroundWorker, but manipulating the raw thread just seemed more natural to me.  If I wanted to use this method, I assume that I would have to build a function on the UI thread to abstract the process of inserting a node into the tree and then safely call that?  reportProgress() seemed to me to be a little misleading as the process actually takes several steps, each modifying different portions of the UI.  That is also part of the reason I chose the design I did as I was hoping that it would be extensible to deal with the Treeview as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. BackgroundWorker does exactly what you want - it is just a wrapper to provide you a "raw" thread to do your background work and a separate callback to do your UI thread. Those two just must be separated, you can't mess with UI in worker thread. It does not even mind if it has several steps, you can use multiple Workers for each. Doing it on your own is very error prone and unnecessary in this scenario.

Comment: in addition to the answer if you don't want to use background worker you can also try one of these 2 

Try to look at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266102/visual-basic-child-thread-blocking-main-thread/17281916#17281916 

answer for in Multithreading example and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142818/new-thread-is-still-blocking-ui-thread?rq=1

answer from ( me ) for In Model Threading.... Those 2 should give you writen code to start aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only place to safely manipulate UI controls is the UI thread. This is so in WinForms and also in WPF. You can either pass back the data to the UI thread and populate the whole tree there or you do something like this (pseudo code):

```
Sub updateView()
   foreach item in data
      mainForm.AddToTreeView(item);
      Thread.Sleep(1);
```

Doing that on a separate thread should avoid overloading the UI thread but it might take a long time to populate. AddToTreeView needs to invoke the add on the UI thread.