# Newly created thread not firing until main thread finished

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I'm extremely novice at threading and I'm simply creating a single thread to run a large function.  I've created a messagebox to appear at the end of the function towards the end of the program to tell me the load time it took.  As i load the application, the messagebox will appear with a time it took and THEN the thread will kick off(although the UI is navigable while the components are loading from the thread) isn't the point of threading to be able to process multiple functions at the same time?   Why is this waiting until the main thread is finished before the new thread kicks off?

I declare and start the new thread early in the app

Comment: You need to show your code

Comment: If you put the message box in the same function as the one that starts the thread, then it is not defined whether the thread will start first or the message box will display. The UI will work because a message box has its own internal event loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For every Form in the application's namespace, there will be a default instance created in the My namespace under the Forms property.**

----------------------**/ Starting Main Thread /**-----------------------------------

```
Private Sub FindCustomerLocation()
Dim Findcontractor_Thread As New Thread(AddressOf **FindContractor_ThreadExecute**)
Findcontractor_Thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal
Findcontractor_Thread.Start(**me**)
End Sub
```

------------------**/ Running Thread /**---------------

```
Private Sub **FindContractor_ThreadExecute**(beginform as *NameOfFormComingFrom*)
Dim threadControls(1) As Object
threadControls(0) = Me.XamDataGrid1
threadControls(1) = Me.WebBrowserMap

 **FindContractor_WorkingThread**(threadControls,beginform) ' ANY UI Calls back to the Main     UI Thread MUST be delegated and Invoked

End Sub
```

------------------**/ How to Set UI Calls from a Thread /** ---------------------

```
Delegate Sub **FindContractor_WorkingThread**(s As Integer,beginform as           *NameOfFormComingFrom*)
Sub **FindContractor_WorkingThreadInvoke**(ByVal s As Integer,beginform as     *NameOfFormComingFrom*)
If beginform.mouse.InvokeRequired Then
Dim d As New FindContractor_WorkingThread(AddressOf            FindContractor_WorkingThreadInvoke)
beginform.Invoke(d, New Object() {s,beginform})
Else
 beginform.Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait

    'Do something...

beginform.Mouse.OverrideCursor = Nothing
 End If
End Sub
```

[Sources from Pakks answer and Tested!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142818/new-thread-is-still-blocking-ui-thread/17343809#17343809)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create multiple threads if you want them to run the way you are thinking (simultaneously).Take a look at this link and try creating more than one thread. This should help your problems. Cheers

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck8bc5c6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx